# Iterator trouble

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I have this code:

```
 if (((boost::get< 1>(*i)) == node1) || ((boost::get< 2>(i*)) == node2))
    {
        cout << "on this tuple "<< boost::get<1>(*i) << "we found it" << endl;

    }
```

And is giving me this error, any idea what is it talking about:

```
 main.cpp:172: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

This is to check a vector of tuples to know which has the value, like so:

```
  void threaded_function(Model_factory &mf, ppa::Node *root)
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(result_mutex);   
  if(!running_jobs.empty())
  {
    boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool>  tuple = running_jobs.front();
    cout << "getting the lock for " << running_jobs.front() << " on " 
            << lock.owns_lock() << endl;
    running_jobs.pop();

    lock.unlock();
    ppa::Node *n = boost::get<0>(tuple);
    ppa::Node *n1 = boost::get<1>(tuple);
    ppa::Node *n2 = boost::get<2>(tuple);
    bool check = boost::get<3>(tuple);
   // n2->start_alignment_new(&mf);
    //n1->start_alignment_new(&mf);
     cout << " name " << n->get_name() << " has seq" << n->node_has_sequence_object<< " " << n->left_child->get_distance_to_parent()
             << " " << n->right_child->get_distance_to_parent() << " this done = " << check << endl;    
    n->start_alignment_new(&mf);



  cout << " name " << n->get_name() << " has seq " << n->node_has_sequence_object<< " " << " lock " << lock.owns_lock() << endl; 


  boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool>  tuple2 = wait.front();
 ppa::Node *node = boost::get<0>(tuple2);
    ppa::Node *node1 = boost::get<1>(tuple2);
    ppa::Node *node2 = boost::get<2>(tuple2);
    bool check2 = boost::get<3>(tuple);

     typedef vector<boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool> >::iterator vec_iter;

    for (vec_iter i = wait.begin(); i != wait.end(); ++i)
    {
    if (((boost::get< 1>(*i)) == node1) || ((boost::get< 2>(i*)) == node2))
    {
        cout << "on this tuple "<< boost::get<1>(*i) << "we found it" << endl;

    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "false found" << endl;
    }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Which line is `line 172`? And why is your code so badly indented?

Comment: if (((boost::get< 1>(*i)) == node1) || ((boost::get< 2>(i*)) == node2)) this is, and because I'm just checking something, I see it ok in netbeans (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typed `i*` instead of `*i` in your second condition:

```
if (((boost::get< 1>(*i)) == node1) || ((boost::get< 2>(i*)) == node2)) 
                                                       ^^^^
```